# IApplicationBuilder does not includes a definition for UseHealthChecks

Tags: kubernetes-health-check

As suggested at the tutorial for [kubernetes health check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-health-probe) I like to implement the health chack at my .NET Core WebApi at class startup.cs at method Configure.
But **the method .UseHealthCheck() is unknown**.
I don't know what creates this problem. I guess all usings are there?!?
[image]

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                "Navigate to /health to see the health status.");
        });
```

here the using:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
```

**How to fix this problem?**

Thanks for your help!
Frank

Comment: Did you add this package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks mxmissile!
I add the NuGet package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks 2.2.0
```

and there for also and first

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.2.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.2.0
Microsoft.Net.Http.headers 2.2.0
```

Now  the method is known.

Comment: I needed to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks package as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've found you only need to install these two

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks 2.2.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks 2.2.0
```